# Failed: no element found using locator: with the Id I use getUserById

Tags: javascript, html, angular, protractor

This is my code in my HTML:

```html
<h1>User list</h1>
<button class="btn btn-primary" [routerLink]="'/register'">Register</button>
<br>
    <br>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">name</th>
                    <th scope="col">email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
                    <th scope="row">{{ user._id }}</th>
                    <td>
                        <a id="getUserById" routerLink="{{ user._id }}">{{ user.name }}</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>{{ user.email }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Protactor does not find my id "getUserById".

This is my test that I am tryint to run:

```js
it('should go to user detail page', async () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
    page.navigateTo('/users/');
    await page.getById.click();
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/users/');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not intimately familiar with Protractor, but it looks like either you haven't passed the id into the function, or the api call is wrong. If you've some sort of wrapper around Protractor then:

```
page.getById.click();
```

perhaps should be

```
page.getById('getUserById').click();
```

Otherwise see docs here:

https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.id

```
await page.getById.click(); therefore should be 


var element = element(by.id('getUserById'))
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

What I guess you are trying a protractor/selenium method for getting the id of element. the best way to do that is to use `element` function i.e. `element(by.id('goBackButton'))`.
Now you can use this for clicking or any thing else.
Lemme know if it helps